# How to import null value in text file into mysql

Tags: mysql, null, mysqlimport

I want to backup some fields of a table using mysql command line in Ubuntu. Output is saved in a text file and import to other table using mysqlimport command.

The problem is with null values each are imported as NULL string in the second table not as what null real meaning.

I have used ISNULL(fieldname, NULL) in select command but no difference.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: First you need to review how your data is saved. The problems lies either in saving or in importing back.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `mysqldump`? I use this to backup my DB (table definitions, data, programs, etc.) and `MySQL MYDB -u ... -p < [backup-file-name]` to update another instance of the database, and it works like a charm!

Comment: mysqldump fetchs all fields of tables but I need a few fields of some tables.